# Reliable statictics of different Windows Phone versions

Tags: 8.0, 8.1, 7.x

I'm a Windows Phone developer and I need to have information on marketshare of different versions of Windows Phone. I'm not interested in other OS, I just need to know marketshare of individual versions of Windows Phone so I can decide whether to develop and support app for particular version or not. I'm particulary interested in Windows Phone 7.X (it's awkward to devlop apps for both WP 7.X and WP 8.X)

I searched the web but I couldn't find any good source.

Comment: IMHO, It's not *that awkward* to develop for 7.x (and upwards) and gives the widest market share as all 7.x apps run on 8.x

Comment: If I develop for 7.x, I will not have features available in 8.x So if I want to develop for both versions I need to have slightly different code for each version.

Comment: There are very few features that aren't available to 7.x phones (notable exceptions: Universal apps, NFC), but that would depend on what you were wanting to develop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adduplex regularly provides statistics on the OS & device market share within the Windows Phone ecosystem. The latest report is from [April 2014](http://blog.adduplex.com/2014/04/adduplex-windows-phone-statistics.html), with WP 7.x running on 19% of the phones.